# Modular Algebra with Powers?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to calculate by modular algebra rules (with no calculators) numbers with powers $\textrm{mod}\ n$? Something like: $7^{127} \textrm{mod}\ 11$. If so, how it can be done? 
Any explanation will be apriciated!

Comment: See [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in Wikipédia. In your case, you can notice $7 \cdot 8 = 1 \pmod{11}$, and compute $7^{127} = 8 \cdot 7^{128} \pmod{11}$, it's a bit easier since $128=2^7$.

Comment: thanks! but can you explain why did you multiply in 8 ?

Comment: Here, $7$ is small, so I simply wrote $7\cdot1, 7\cdot2...$ until I found a multiple of $11$ plus $1$. Hence $8$ is the inverse of $7$ modulo $11$. For larger number, there is [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), used to solve Bezout's equation, which you can use to find modular inverses: solve equation $x\cdot n + y\cdot m = 1$ where $m$ is your modulus, $n$ the number to inverse, and $x$ the solution ($y$ is not useful, but you'll find it too).

Comment: Of course, to compute $a^b \mod m$, you don't use modular inverses usually (unless $b \lt 0$ or you compute by hand and you want to speed things up). Using a calculator or a computer, you just use the *squaring* algorithm, which is fast enough.

Comment: thanks a lot! it was really helpful :)

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) is also interesting.

Comment: @arbautjc so if I understand it well, after we get to 
8*7^(128) and since 128 is 2^7, then we'll get
(8*2) (mod11) and this equals 5.. right?

Comment: No, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,
$$7^{127} \equiv 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 7^{127} \equiv 8 \cdot 7^{128} \equiv 8 \cdot 7^{2^7} \pmod{11}$$

Now, step by step:
$$7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$$
$$5^2 \equiv 25 \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$$
$$3^2 \equiv 9 \equiv -2 \pmod{11}$$
$$(-2)^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$$
$$4^2 \equiv 16 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$$
You have still two squares to compute, but you can find them already computed above:
$$5^2 \equiv 25 \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$$
$$3^2 \equiv 9 \equiv -2 \pmod{11}$$

Now, we have squared $7$ times, so we have computed:
$$\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(7^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2 \equiv 7^{2^7} \equiv -2 \pmod{11}$$

And finally
$$7^{127} \equiv 8 \cdot 7^{128} \equiv 8 \cdot -2 \equiv -16 \equiv 6 \pmod{11}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem,  $7^{10}\equiv1\pmod {11}$ as $(7,11)=1$

So, $7^{127}=(7^{10})^{12}\cdot 7^7\equiv 7^7\pmod {11}$

$7^1\equiv7 \pmod {11}, 7^2=49\equiv5, 7^4\equiv 5^2\equiv 3$
$\implies 7^7=7^1\cdot7^2\cdot7^4\equiv 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\pmod{11}\equiv105\equiv6$

Answer (score 1):

Little Fermat $\rm\:\Rightarrow\:mod\ 11\!:\ \color{#c00}{2^{10}}\!\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\: 7^{127}\!\equiv (-2^2)^{127}\!\equiv 2^{254}\!\equiv - 2^4 (\color{#c00}{2^{10}})^{25}\!\equiv -16\equiv 6$

**Remark** $\ $ For small numbers one may often employ intuition to find optimizations like this. Otherwise one may employ brute-force algorithms such as [exponentiation by repeated squaring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Answer (score 1):

$7^3 \equiv 2 (\mod 11)$

$2^5 \equiv (-1 \mod 11) \implies7^{15} \equiv -1 \implies7^{120} \equiv1 (\mod 11)$

$7^3 \times 7^3 \times 7 \equiv 2 \times 2 \times 7 (\mod 11) \equiv11 \cdot2+6 (\mod 11)$

$7^7 \equiv 6 (\mod 11) \implies 7^{127} \equiv 6 (\mod 11)$